# ReactJS how to access content output from a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill

I'm currently working on a project that uses QuillJS for a rich text editor. I need to post the rich text content to my backend but I'm not sure how to access the QuillJS output.

***In RichTextEditor.js***

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactQuill from "react-quill";
import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";
class RichTextEditor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // this.formats = formats;
    this.state = { text: "" }; // You can also pass a Quill Delta here
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(value) {
    this.setState({ text: value });
    const text = this.state;
    console.log(text);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ReactQuill
        value={this.state.text}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        formats={this.formats}
        modules={this.modules}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default RichTextEditor;
```

The `console.log(text)` basically just outputs the content of the rich text editor. Something like this `"<p><em>aasdasdasd</em><strong><em>asdasdasdasd</em></strong></p>"`

***In Post.js***

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import RichTextEditor from "./RichTextEditor.js";

import "../../css/Post.css";

class Post extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      question: "",
    };
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    console.log(this.state);
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { question } = this.state;

    console.log("Question");
    console.log(question);

  render() {
    const { question } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="post">
        <div className="post__container">
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="post__richTextEditor">
              <RichTextEditor value={question} onChange={this.onChange} name="question" />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Post;
```

I'm trying to update the state of the question but it doesn't seem to be updating. `console.log(question)` only outputs a single string.

How can I access the same string output from RichTextEditor.js?

Answer (score 0):

Your RichTextEditor component should not handle change, it should only receive props from higher component:

```
class RichTextEditor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ReactQuill
        value={this.props.value}
        onChange={this.props.onChange}
        formats={this.formats}
        modules={this.modules}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default RichTextEditor;
```

Then your Post component pass `value` and `onChange` props to RichTextEditor:

```
class Post extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      question: "",
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    console.log(this.state);
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { question } = this.state;

    console.log("Question");
    console.log(question);

  render() {
    const { question } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="post">
        <div className="post__container">
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="post__richTextEditor">
              <RichTextEditor value={question} onChange={this.onChange} name="question" />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in `RichTextEditor.js`

```
 handleChange(value) {
    this.setState({ text: value });
    const text = this.state;
    console.log(text);
    props.onChange(text); // passing the inner State to parent as argument to onChange handler
  }
```

Now in `Post.js`

```
onChange = (newStateString) => {
    //this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    console.log(newStateString);  // you should get the string here
  };
```